# Cartesian product $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone tell me whether $\Bbb R^{n+m}$ equals Cartesian product $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ for some positive integers $n$ and $m$?

Comment: What exactly does "equals" mean to you here?

Comment: Under the usual take-away-those-four-parenthesis identification, yes. Though, technically, in set theory they are two different things.

Comment: I'm prettyyyyy sure that this is a duplicate.

Comment: It seem to me for any positive integers $k$ and $s$, for which it is true that $k+s = m+n$, $R^{n+m} = R^{k} \times R^{s}$

Comment: @HenningMakholm They are perfectly equal if you define it in terms of basis vectors e_1, e_2,e_3... without using tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes. The objects in $\Bbb R^{n+m}$ are represented by $n+m$-tuples. That is, something of the form $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{n+m})$. The objects in $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ would be written
$$((r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n),(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m)),$$
where $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)$ is in $\Bbb R^n$ and $(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_m)$ is in $\Bbb R^m$.

You can see that the difference is only cosmetic, and you might as well relabel the elements of $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m$ so that they look the same as those in $\Bbb R^{n+m}$. We call these two spaces isomorphic.

Comment: Define "cosmetic". There difference is notable. One is a set of ordered pairs, and another is a set of $n+m$-tuples. What you want to say is that there is a natural and obvious way of identifying between the two sets. So equality only holds in the case where $n=m=1$, and that only if you define ordered pairs as $2$-tuples to begin with.

Comment: I think the best way to see this is categorically. Once you know that Set has products, you can easily show that $\mathbb R ^{n+m}$ and $\mathbb   R^n\times \mathbb R^m$ are both products in the categorical sense, in that they satisfy a certain universal mapping property. They are therefore isomorphic, in fact $naturally$ isomorphic.